# Solr disable synonyms and stopwords

Tags: solr

Is there a way to completely disable Solr synonyms and stopwords from index and querying times without changing the schema.xml? I could not find something useful on the internet.

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: If the files are empty, no replacement or removal will happen. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. Apart from that is there any config?

Comment: No - since that's the role of the schema, but changing the schema doesn't have to involve editing the `schema.xml` file directly. You can use the SchemaAPI to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter factories for stopwords and synonyms are pointing to textfiles, where all of  the synonyms and stopwords are set. If you remove all the entries from those files, you will get something like an disabled synonyms- & stopwords- feature.

But: keep in mind, that stopwords and sysnonyms, which are generated on index-time are available as long as you re-index your core.